# Hide columns from SELECT clause conditionally

Tags: mysql

I want to hide columns conditionally from a SELECT clause in a MySQL store procedure. The query is

```
SELECT year,gwp_amount,claim_amount,cancellation_amount from tmptable;
```

I want to show `gwp_amount,claim_amount,cancellation_amount` columns conditionally,

sometimes I want to show `gwp_amount and claim_amount` columns,

sometimes `gwp_amount and cancellation_amount` columns,

sometimes `one of the column` and

sometimes `all three columns`.

I pass three indicators in store procedure like gwp_ind, calim_ind, cancellation_ind.

I want to show these columns according to these parameters.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? All rows in a relation, by definition, have the same set of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use the CASE statement.... SELECT year, (Case  when gwp_ind =
>   True THEN gwp_amount, when calim_ind= True THEN claim_amount, when
>   cancellation_ind= True THEN cancellation_amount ELSE 0 END) as amount
>   from tmptable;
>
> You can use above query If you have according to your requirements.
>   But according to question we cannot select dynamically columns in
>   SELECT Clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).

```
SELECT year, (IF gwp_amount < 2, NULL, gwp_amount) FROM tmptable;
```

If you want to make the projection conditional, you have to do this in your application by dynamically creating the SQL query. I. e. you have to phrase separate queries for each case. This is not possible with SQL alone. The nearest thing what you could do is phrase a query which is not conditional in its column count. E.g.:

```
SELECT (IF gwp_amount < 2, gwp_amount, claim_amount) FROM tmptable;
```

This makes a projection on either `gwp_amount` or `claim_amount`. But it's not possible to make something which projects either `gwp_amount` or `gwp_amount` and `claim_amount`.

Comment: Thanks for response, If I can use IF then I can show only one column like if (gwp_ind, gwp_amount, claim_amount). this is not my question I want to show multiple columns some times. I can achieve my goal using IF statement in procedure but this is not good programming practice. like if gwp_ind then SELECT year,gwp_amount from tmptable else if gwp_ind and claim_ind then SELECT year,gwp_amount,claim_amountfrom tmptable end if; and so on. but I think this is not good practice.

Comment: @KamranAslam, You want show columns dynamically? I think that is not possible.